# IBTool fails Xcode 9.2 iOS 11.3

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, ibtool

I'm trying to create a project in Xamarin Forms 
But whenever I launch the new created project Ibtool fails with error code 255

Xcode 9.2 + iOS 11.3

Cleaning the solution, restarting visual/OS doesn't work.

I can't create any project at all, be it forms or native or whatever I get instantly this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Close VS for Mac
2. Open Xcode
3. Xcode prompted me to update additional components
4. Click Install
5. Close Xcode
6. Reopen VS for Mac